# how to make a triangle button in flex using custom component?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

I need a button that has a triangle shape.

how to make a custom component like a triangle button in flex?

what class should i override? updateDisplayList()? or layoutChrom()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on how complex you want the button to be you might be able to get away with using a process like [this](http://www.patrickhansen.com/blog/2010/07/16/custom-spark-button-skin-using-fx-gmxml/) - except make the color outside the triangle the same for the 'clicked' and 'unclicked' states. Only change the color inside the triangle for the selected state.

If you need something more complex you can start with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1291050/flex-custom-button-component) or [this](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=intro_3.html) for guidance.

Comment: thanks for the ref. I used the graphics to draw the triangle for the button.